# How to make an input field maxlength work from a keypad?

Tags: javascript, html

Got an input field that has a maxlength of 6, when typing normally it works fine, but when I try to use the keypad I made, it doesn't. It just seems to bypass the limit as if it isn't even there.

HTML:

```
    <div class="bank-screen">
  <h1>Please enter your pin to continue</h1>
  <div class="options">
    <input name="pin" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
    type = "number"
    maxlength = "4"
    id="pinfield">
  </div>
  <div class="keypad">
    <div class="keys">   
    <button value="1" class="key" onclick="GetNum(this)">1</button>
    <button value="2" class="key" onclick="GetNum(this)">2</button>
    <button value="3" class="key" onclick="GetNum(this)">3</button>
    <button value="4" class="key" onclick="GetNum(this)">4</button>
    <button value="5" class="key" onclick="GetNum(this)">5</button>
    <button value="6" class="key" onclick="GetNum(this)">6</button>
    <button value="7" class="key" onclick="GetNum(this)">7</button>
    <button value="8" class="key" onclick="GetNum(this)">8</button>
    <button value="9" class="key" onclick="GetNum(this)">9</button>
    <button class="key"></button>
    <button value="0" class="key" onclick="GetNum(this)">0</button>
    <button class="key"></button>
    <button class="key" id="submit">Submit</button>
    <button class="key" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button class="key" id="clear" onclick="clearall()">Clear</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function GetNum(a){
var pinfield = document.getElementById("pinfield");
pinfield.value = pinfield.value + a.value;
```

}

```
function clearall(){
var pinfield = document.getElementById("pinfield");
pinfield.value = null;
```

}

```
var result = 103/50;
result = Math.floor(result);


console.log(result);
```

Comment: you may need to use combination of keyup keydown and change events to detect length  and control over it...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that setting the input value via JavaScript will ignore the length limit.

In your case, you can add some validation in your `GetNum` function, only adding to the input field if the current value is shorter than 4 characters.

```js
function GetNum(a){
  var pinfield = document.getElementById("pinfield");
  if (pinfield.value.length < 6) {
    pinfield.value = pinfield.value + a.value;
  }
}
```